# Magento2 on enable static asset signing - file not found

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to deploy the static assets using the command:
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Also removed the var folder.
after that if I load the site in browser, the css, js files from source are not loaded. 
for example the link in the source looks like this:
`http://www.example.com/pub/static/version1503771754/_cache/merged/f02fb718e9807603b4bf524157f9fd9b.min.css`

when I check the file physical location:
`http://www.example.com/pub/static/_cache/merged/f02fb718e9807603b4bf524157f9fd9b.min.css`
the file is very much there.
so the signing of the file is making it unreachable.

But If I disable the signing I am getting a 500 internal server error on backend.

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.
if anyone faces the same problem. 
The file .htaccess was not correct. I downloaded the latest and correct version the file and put it in pub/static/ folder and run the command again also removed the `var` folder all caches.

This resolved the problem.